# In app billing purchase fails with no reason given

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using a test google checkout account, when I try to do a purchase I get an error when the order is being authorized ('authorize payment' is displayed), this usually happens about 30 seconds after the order has been placed (i.e. 'accept & buy' has been tapped):

"Your payment could not be processed. sign in to your google wallet account to request support"

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You also can't purchase your own products i.e. release app and buy items with same google id

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the bank information to the merchant account ?
Are you still experiencing this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, problem got fixed when I changed the API version number inside makeRequestBundle() method of BillingService.Java:

request.putInt(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION, 1);

to

request.putInt(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION, 2);

Hope it helps!